# Delete user meta based on key value that is an array

Tags: plugins, mysql

I have a user meta key `prize` which is an array contains `prize type` and `prize date`.
The date in unix timestamp.
How I can delete the user meta by specify the prize date only?

Example code:

```
delete_user_meta( $userID, 'prize', $meta_value ); 
$meta_value = array(
    'prize' => array(
         // Add something here like prize date = 1506556467
    ) , 
);
```

Key value in the database look like this:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:17:"prize name";i:1;i:1506556467;}
```

And what if I want to delete the metakeys if the value in between 2 integer like `1506550000` and `1506550001` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `$meta_value` is optional and I you will be having a unique entry of prize for each user so you can just use the function without `$meta_value`.

```
delete_user_meta( $userID, 'prize' );
```